# How to create a 6" hole template with a 1/4" bit and 5/16" template guide?

Tags: router, router-bit, template

I need to make MANY 6" holes using a router.  If I use a 5/16" template guide and a 1/4" straight bit, what size hole must I make the template?  I don't have much scrap to experiment with.  My gut tells me I need to divide the difference of 5/16"-1/4" in half and then add that to the radius of the circle... but that sounds wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the link below...

> **Figuring template offset**
> Offset is the distance from the outside of the guide bushing tube to the cutting edge of the router bit. This dimension determines where the bit cuts the workpiece.
>
> To figure the offset, measure the outside diameter (OD) of the guide bushing tube and subtract the diameter of the bit. Next, divide this figure by 2 to determine the offset. In the example at right, subtract the 1⁄2 " bit diameter from the bushing's 3⁄4 " OD. You get 1⁄4 ". Now divide this number by two and you arrive at a 1⁄8 " offset.

[image: drawing of how to calculate template offset]

[Understanding Guide Bushings - WoodMagazine.Com](https://www.woodmagazine.com/woodworking-tips/techniques/routing/understanding-guide-bushings)

Comment: More simply: *the template offset is the difference between the radius of the bushing and the radius of the bit*.